# Block until element is available

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a multithreaded program where one thread is reading data and multiple others are doing work on that data. If I have one writing thread continuously adding data (`Example.add()`) and the other reader threads sequentially reading that data (`Example.getData(1)`, `Example.getData(2)`, ...), what is the best way to block the readers until data at the index they are requesting is available?

This problem is kind of like producer-consumer, but I don't want to "consume" the data.

```
public class Example {
  private ArrayList<Integer> data;

  public Example() {
    data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }

  public int getData(int i) {
    // I want to block here until the element
    // index i is available.

    return data.get(i);
  }

  public void add(int n) {
    data.add(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want either `Future` (built in to Java, but more limited) or a `Promise` (newer, and part of the Reactor specification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a reasonable way to synchronize threads:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html

The Condition link shows an example of this:

```
class BoundedBuffer {
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition(); 
    final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition(); 

    final Object[] items = new Object[100];
    int putptr, takeptr, count;

    public void put(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (count == items.length)
                notFull.await();
            items[putptr] = x;
            if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;
            ++count;
            notEmpty.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public Object take() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (count == 0)
                notEmpty.await();
            Object x = items[takeptr];
            if (++takeptr == items.length) takeptr = 0;
                --count;
            notFull.signal();
            return x;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Please don't judge me on the code style this is a straight copy from the example in Condition.

In your case you might consider using a single lock which all threads wait on, that signals when new elements are added. this would cause all threads to wake up and test if their element is there yet. if not they go back to wait for the next signal.

If you want them to specifically wait for the 1 element you could keep a signal per element but that seems overkill.

something like:

```
public class Example {
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition update = lock.newCondition();
    public Example(data) {
        data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public int getData(int i) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (data.get(i) == null) {
                update.await();
            }
            return data.get(i);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void add(int n) {
        data.add(n);
        update.signal();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail about the _Basically_?

Comment: Sure.. felt that the example in the condition link covered most of his use case. and was lazy :D  also above code is me coding somewhat drunk so who knows if it works. I think it does but :) needs testing.

the "Example(data)" I left in as the OP used this exact form. it may be wrong but didn't want to correct his example

Comment: I quite like this method, @Joeblade. I tried it out and made some updates to your code example in case anyone ever needs to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use blocking queue in java. When the queue is empty it blocks for the queue to have data until it is consumed. You can find more information about it here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Lookup some examples online for Java blocking queue and you can solve your issue

Comment: A queue doesn't support their indexing requirement.

Comment: maybe a custom data structure which uses blocking queue internally to implement this functionality.